# How to count the number of occurrences of each distinct element in a column of a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a `dataframe` in the following format:

```
-------------------------------
   col1    |  col2    | col3
-------------------------------
value11    | value21  | value31
value12    | value22  | value32
value11    | value22  | value33
value12    | value21  | value33
```

Here, column `col1` has `value11, value12` as distinct value. I want the total number of occurrences of each distinct value `value11, value12` of column `col1`.

Comment: Have you tried to write a SQL statement over that? Any errors when you tried?

Comment: I got the answer. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I was just wondering what you've attempted

Comment: Initially, I was creating dataframe for each column and finding the distinct values for each dataframe then for each distinct value I was iterating, which was inefficient way and taking the huge amount of time.

Comment: You tagged the question with SparkSQL, so I assumed you would have at least tried `SELECT col1, COUNT(*) FROM dataframe GROUP BY col1`

Comment: I could have tried this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupBy` *col1*, then `count`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.count

df.groupBy("col1").agg(count("col1")).show
+-------+-----------+
|   col1|count(col1)|
+-------+-----------+
|value12|          2|
|value11|          2|
+-------+-----------+
```

---

In case you want to know how many distinct values there are in *col1*, you can use `countDistinct`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct

df.agg(countDistinct("col1").as("n_distinct")).show
+----------+
|n_distinct|
+----------+
|         2|
+----------+
```

Comment: I am getting an error `not found: value count`. Do I have to import anything?

Comment: Yes you can import it from `sql.functions.`